# Bootstrap Select2 ProcessResults Not Firing

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, web-services, webforms, jquery-select2

I'm having issues getting my json result options to populate using Select2 v4 (https://select2.github.io/). I must be overlooking something small, just can't put a finger on it...

Dropdown:

```
    <select id="e1" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#e1").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,  
            ajax: {
                url: "/Empl.asmx/AccessRemoteData",  
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term
                    };
                },
                // Why is this never called???
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3
        });
    </script>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebUI
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Empl : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public class Select2DTO
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string AccessRemoteData(string q)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictCountry = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictCountry.Add("1", "India");
            dictCountry.Add("2", "Canada");
            dictCountry.Add("3", "United States");
            dictCountry.Add("4", "United Kingdom");
            dictCountry.Add("5", "United Arab Emirates");
            List<object> CountryList = new List<object>();
            Select2DTO singleCountry;

            var selectedCountryList = dictCountry.Where(m => m.Value.ToLower().Contains(q)).ToList();
            foreach (var selectedCountry in selectedCountryList)
            {
                singleCountry = new Select2DTO();
                singleCountry.id = selectedCountry.Key;
                singleCountry.text = selectedCountry.Value;
                CountryList.Add(singleCountry);
            }

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CountryList, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None });
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

The web service is being called. If I go to http://localhost:52657/Empl.asmx/AccessRemoteData?q=united I get the following results:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"id":"3","text":"United States"},{"id":"4","text":"United Kingdom"},{"id":"5","text":"United Arab Emirates"}]
</string>
```

If I put a breakpoint in "processResults" on the client side it never gets hit. I read several other posts this morning and can't seem to find the issue.

Any help out there?

Comment: Actually this entire issue exists because you're trying to out-think ASP.Net web services. You need to return only `List<Select2DTO>` to client side.
A great article explaining all this (a very common pitfall) is [this](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/)

Comment: Thank you for this! Excellent article and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this entire issue exists because you're trying to out-think ASP.Net web services. You need to return only `List<Select2DTO>` to client side. A great article explaining all this (a very common pitfall) is [this](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<object> AccessRemoteData(string q)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictCountry = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictCountry.Add("1", "India");
        dictCountry.Add("2", "Canada");
        dictCountry.Add("3", "United States");
        dictCountry.Add("4", "United Kingdom");
        dictCountry.Add("5", "United Arab Emirates");
        List<object> CountryList = new List<object>();
        Select2DTO singleCountry;

        var selectedCountryList = dictCountry.Where(m => m.Value.ToLower().Contains(q)).ToList();
        foreach (var selectedCountry in selectedCountryList)
        {
            singleCountry = new Select2DTO();
            singleCountry.id = selectedCountry.Key;
            singleCountry.text = selectedCountry.Value;
            CountryList.Add(singleCountry);
        }

        return CountryList;
    }
```